# render only 10 item in react native flatlist on each page, then the next 5 on pull to load more item

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-flatlist

i want to do paging but i cant limit the item to 10. this code shows all the items.
these are not  working as well -initialNumToRender,maxToRenderPerBatch,windowSize

```
<FlatList
        data={DATA}
        renderItem={({ item }) => (
    <Item title={item.name} />
  )}
        keyExtractor={item => item.id}
         ItemSeparatorComponent={ItemSeparatorView}
         initialNumToRender={11}
         maxToRenderPerBatch={5}
         windowSize={2}

      />
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this,

```js
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
 
//import all the components we are going to use
import {
  SafeAreaView,
  View,
  Text,
  TouchableOpacity,
  StyleSheet,
  FlatList,
  ActivityIndicator,
} from 'react-native';
 
const App = () => {
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const [dataSource, setDataSource] = useState([]);
  const [offset, setOffset] = useState(1);
 
  useEffect(() => getData(), []);
 
  const getData = () => {
    console.log('getData');
    setLoading(true);
    //Service to get the data from the server to render
    fetch('https://aboutreact.herokuapp.com/getpost.php?offset='
          + offset)
      //Sending the currect offset with get request
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((responseJson) => {
        //Successful response
        setOffset(offset + 1);
        //Increasing the offset for the next API call
        setDataSource([...dataSource, ...responseJson.results]);
        setLoading(false);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error(error);
      });
  };
 
  const renderFooter = () => {
    return (
      //Footer View with Load More button
      <View style={styles.footer}>
        <TouchableOpacity
          activeOpacity={0.9}
          onPress={getData}
          //On Click of button load more data
          style={styles.loadMoreBtn}>
          <Text style={styles.btnText}>Load More</Text>
          {loading ? (
            <ActivityIndicator
              color="white"
              style={{marginLeft: 8}} />
          ) : null}
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    );
  };
 
  const ItemView = ({item}) => {
    return (
      // Flat List Item
      <Text
        style={styles.itemStyle}
        onPress={() => getItem(item)}>
        {item.id}
        {'.'}
        {item.title.toUpperCase()}
      </Text>
    );
  };
 
  const ItemSeparatorView = () => {
    return (
      // Flat List Item Separator
      <View
        style={{
          height: 0.5,
          width: '100%',
          backgroundColor: '#C8C8C8',
        }}
      />
    );
  };
 
  const getItem = (item) => {
    //Function for click on an item
    alert('Id : ' + item.id + ' Title : ' + item.title);
  };
 
  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={{flex: 1}}>
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <FlatList
          data={dataSource}
          keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
          ItemSeparatorComponent={ItemSeparatorView}
          enableEmptySections={true}
          renderItem={ItemView}
          ListFooterComponent={renderFooter}
        />
      </View>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
};
 
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    justifyContent: 'center',
    flex: 1,
  },
  footer: {
    padding: 10,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    flexDirection: 'row',
  },
  loadMoreBtn: {
    padding: 10,
    backgroundColor: '#800000',
    borderRadius: 4,
    flexDirection: 'row',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  btnText: {
    color: 'white',
    fontSize: 15,
    textAlign: 'center',
  },
});
 
export default App;
```